# Trying to hide SearchBar through Alpha in Swift

Tags: swift, scroll, uisearchbar, alpha, navigationbar

I'm using Xcode 9 and Swift 4. I'm having trouble trying to use the scroll in y to hide SearchBar through alpha. How to access this background to try to hide it? 
code:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let transp:Float = Float(1 - (self.mTableView.contentOffset.y / (self.mTableView.contentSize.height - self.mTableView.frame.size.height) * 60))
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.alpha = CGFloat(transp)
    self.mSearchController.searchBar.alpha = CGFloat(transp)
    self.mSearchController.searchBar.isTranslucent = true
    titleMsgView.alpha = CGFloat(transp)
}
```

Here's a sample gif link:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/6is5mukpk1yew8e/bgSearch.gif?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

The SearchView is pretty tough when it comes to changing how it looks. You could try looping over the subviews of the SearchView and setting all their alpha values to 0, like this:

```
for subView in mSearchController.searchBar.subviews {
    subView.alpha = 0
    for deepSubView in subView.subviews {
        deepSubView.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

Also, a quick note: you can remove a lot of the `self` keywords from your code.

EDIT: That just removed the searchbar, but with some editing we can fix that:

```
for subview in mSearchController.searchBar.subviews.last!.subviews {
    if type(of: subview) == NSClassFromString("UISearchBarBackground") {
        subview.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Thank you, I removed the "self". Using the code you posted, it hid the SearchBar search field.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/f6mel4ra2kmzg3z/bgSearch2.gif?dl=0

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro Hey, I've added more code which should help you :)

Comment: You literally copy and pasted the code, without changing names? I will make some changes for you.

Comment: Sorry, I never worked with subviews. I do not understand anything.

Comment: It's very weird. Now it does not show a gray background, but rather white. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fgu84mipa4o27wd/screen3.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Is there a problem in my storyboard?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqcbubw6s1318xk/screen2.jpeg?dl=0

Comment: Thanks, I added the new code. It's very weird. Now it does not show a gray background, but rather white. https://www.dropbox.com/s/fgu84mipa4o27wd/screen3.jpeg?dl=0